# How to redirect multiple similar URLs with one query?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect

I currently have lots of URLs that look like this:

http://www.domain.com/classes-dallas-tx.html

I need to change all URLs to the following:

http://www.domain.com/classes-in-dallas-tx.html

I just need to add the "in" into every URL that doesn't have it right now.

Is there one query I can use for the .htaccess file that will take care of all the URLs for me?  I'm planning on using the 301 redirect.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide more examples of your current and to be changed URLs.

Comment: Hi... all the URLs are very much alike except for the city and state. For example, here are the current URLs I'd like to change:
http://www.domain.com/classes-dallas-tx.html, http://www.domain.com/classes-houston-tx.html, http://www.domain.com/classes-austin-tx.html. I want to change them to include an "in": http://www.domain.com/classes-in-dallas-tx.html, http://www.domain.com/classes-in-houston-tx.html, http://www.domain.com/classes-in-austin-tx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-in-$2-$3.html
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-in-$2-$3.html [L,R=301]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Awesome! The first one worked!  Is there a preference between the two as far as Google and SEO is concerned?

Comment: @user1858780 One uses mod_alias (the first) and the other uses mod_rewrite. There's no difference as far as Google can tell, but directives could interfere with each other if you are using directives from both modules at the same time.

Comment: Hi all, it seems this code has stopped working for me. It was fine for a long time, and now it's causing errors. I have this code:
'code'
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-in-$2-$3.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
'code'
URL Switch I'd like:

domain.com/music-classes-dallas-tx.html
to
domain.com/music-classes-in-dallas-tx.html