# Redirect 301 code stopped working

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need some help to figure out why my code is no longer working.

Original Thread:
[How to redirect multiple similar URLs with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598802/how-to-redirect-multiple-similar-urls-with-one-query)

Please see the original question.

It seems the code has stopped working for me. It was fine for a long time, and now it's causing errors. I have this code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-in-$2-$3.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
```

URL Switch I'd like:

`domain.com/music-classes-dallas-tx.html` to `domain.com/music-classes-in-dallas-tx.html`

Does anyone know why this could've stopped working? What can I change to make it work again?

Comment: Have you tried using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

Comment: Sorry had the wrong link to the original thread in my post. I have updated it. Original thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598802/how-to-redirect-multiple-similar-urls-with-one-query

Comment: Mike, I have not tried that. I'm not sure what it would look like. Mind sharing the code and I can give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This methodology is incorrect, due to the variance in file names. See the comment below.

---

Using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you can use the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Condition: First, check that `-in-` is not contained in the request URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-in- [NC]

# Rule: If it isn't, redirect the old page to the new one
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)-([a-z]+)-([a-z]{2})\.html$ /$1-in-$2-$3.html [NC,L,R=301]
```

If you'd also like ensure that the file being redirected to actually exists, you can add this just under the condition specified above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to redirect.

The link I have is:

domain.com/music-classes-death-valley-ca.html ... it's not moving me to domain.com/music-classes-in-death-valley-ca.html

Comment: It should be. Tests are working on my side. Anything else in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I actually see that my methodology is incorrect... The thing is that some paths will have `something-something-tx` and others will have `something-tx`. As such, it is difficult to determine exactly where the `-in-` should go... With that said, I think it would be better for you to stick to the old URI patterns, especially since keywords like `in` are not recognised by search engines (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Thanks for trying. The weird thing is that the prior way worked before. I'll paste my htaccess shortly.

Comment: Here is the code in my .htaccess that worked before: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]{2})\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3-$4.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.html$ /$1-$2-in-$3.html`

Comment: Like I said, it's difficult for it to guess where the `-in-` must go. Your code won't work for `music-classes-death-valley-ca.html` because there are five parameters to catch, not four. If we were to add a another parameter to the first `RedirectMatch`, it would work (becoming `music-classes-in-death-valley-ca.html`). However, it would not work with this file: `arts-crafts-classes-brooklyn-ny.html` because it would become `arts-crafts-in-classes-brooklyn-ny.html`. How many files do you have that need to be redirected?

Comment: We got lots Mike... 30K... it's OK though, I can just have Google recrawl the proper URLs. I am getting some 404 not found errors on Webmaster Tools right now because this isn't working. It used to redirect them before when the old URLs were in place.

Comment: Looking at the error log on Google, it's only for the two word cities like death valley, so it seems the single city names are still working with my code, it's just these that won't catch.